# CSS grid border without content

Tags: css, border, css-grid

Is there a simple way to add borders to a CSS grid that has no content ?
Say I make a grid with 3 lines & 4 rows:

CSS

```
    .container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
    </div>
```

How would I visualize the layout of the entire grid without having to fill it with child containers that all have borders on their own ?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't. Grid areas are not elements and so cannot be styled. Use the developer tools that come with your browser.

Comment: Thank you, will do!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the webpage, open the developer tools, inside the inspector tab, go in the layout section, and should be showing the div you applied `display: grid` to, just check the box in front of it and you will be able to see your grid layout on the page

Refer to this: https://ibb.co/pf8mSyv

Comment: Cool this will do. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Give a height property

```
height: 50px;
```

or something like that.